# Sylow $3$-subgroups of $U_{11}$ and $D_{20}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

This includes two separate but related questions: I have an exercise that asks me to find a Sylow $2$-subgroup and a Sylow $3$-subgroup of $U_{11}$ (the group of multiplicative units $mod$ $11$), and another that asks me to find a Sylow $2$-subgroup, a Sylow $3$-subgroup and a Sylow $5$-subgroup of $D_{20}$ (the group of symmetries of a regular decahedron). But, we have $|U_{11}|=10$, $|D_{20}|=20$, and $3$ divides neither $10$ nor $20$, so by Lagrange's theorem, both of these groups cannot have a subgroup of order $3^n$. Is this all there is to it (so the questions were probably trick questions), or is there something obvious that I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's actually past exam questions that I'm doing for practice. Initially I thought it was a typo, but then it repeated, so it made me think there was something more to it. Question 5a in this 
 https://qmplus.qmul.ac.uk/pluginfile.php/2476721/mod_resource/content/2/6106_2021-sample.pdf

Comment: Aaah, see! "Find a Sylow 2-subgroup, and Sylow 3-subgroup *and a Sylow 5-subgroup*. That makes sense. This is not a typo, of course.

Comment: And I cannot paste the other since it its a pdf in my files, but it just asked: Find a Sylow $2$-subgroup and a Sylow $3$-subgroup of $U_{11}$

Comment: Yes, but giving more context is really helpful here. Then it becomes clear what the intention of this exam question is. I leave it to you. You should have realized it by now :)

Comment: Wait so these are indeed typos after all, right? :P

Comment: No, there are **not**. This is the point (which becomes only clear if you add more context - next time you should add more context immediately).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118207/discussion-between-jbuck-and-dietrich-burde).

Comment: You wrote that a group that is not divisible by $3$ cannot have a subgroup of order $3^n$ by Lagrange's Theorem. There is a small mistake there - think about it!

Comment: @DerekHolt I've been thinking about this for the last hour, but I cannot still cannot find my mistake, so could you give me a hint? Apart from that, I am certain that $U_{11}$ does not have a subgroup of order $3^n$, since it is isomorphic to $C_{10}$. I am also confident that the same is true for $D_{20}$, and I've been counting each one of its subgroups to make sure, so I still think the questions are probably meant to be answered like"There exists no such subgroup.", in both cases. Again, please point out any mistake. Thank you!

Comment: You can take $n=0$. All finite groups have a Sylow $3$-subgroup. When the order of the group is not divisible by $3$, then this subgroup is the trivial subgroup containing the identity only.

Comment: Oh so it was this after all... I immediately considered this case, but I was looking for a non-trivial such subgroup. I thought, perhaps erroneously, that the definition of a Sylow $p$-subgroup excludes the trivial group. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: To be fair, many textbooks are unclear on this point, and sometimes they only define Sylow $p$-subgroups for groups with order divisible by $p$. But it is really much more convenient to allow the trivial subgroup, because then you don't have to keep repeating the hypothesis about $p$ dividing $|G|$, which is nearly always unnecessary.